# Как открыть WinForms на macOS?

Tags: c#, .net, macos, mono

Как открыть проект, использующий WinForms на моем macOS (BigSur на чипе M1)?

У меня есть проект написанный на Windows с использованием WinForms и передо мной стоит задача открыть его на моем macOS.

В интернете я нашел, что с помощью Mono можно открыть такой проект, но спустя несколько часов открытий через консоль, изменения Mono на 32-bit версию и докачки Xamarin, XCode все равно ничего не открывается и в интернете буквально кончились версии как это возможно и остается только то, что это невозможно и открытие только с помощью виртуальной машины, но я все же хочу найти решение поэтому прошу помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такого решения не существует.

Во-первых винформс не предназначен для запуска на других операционных системах в принципе.

Во-вторых моно не поддерживает винформс и WPF именно по этой причине. Хочешь один единый юай на несколько операционных систем - используй для этого тот инструмент который может запускаться на нескольких операционных системах. Например веб-юай. Или GTK#. Или любой другой который найдешь в поиске.

Тем более что ты хочешь запускать еще и приложение на ARM процессоре. Там есть сложности даже при билдании из макос, не говоря о кросплатформенных программах.

## Хочешь запускать винформс приложение - у тебя единый выход - ***Wine***.

К слову - еще и любая х86 программа запускаемая на этом процессоре по-факту запускается через виртуальную машину в любом случае. Только эта виртуальная машина уже называется Rosetta. Так что ты хотел променять одну виртуальную машину на другую сам того, даже, не осознавая.